# SQL Server Authentication vs Windows Authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am a SQL Server newbie and would really appreciate any help.

I have created a new login (test2) with sql server authentication and granted select & vierw definition permission on another schema (test1) to test2. I am however not able to see the objects of test1 in the object explorer. However I can select the objects from the Query Window.

Since this new login is being used to develop reports the user would like to view the objects in the Object Explorer.

Another user test3 created using windows authentication and similar permissions is able to see test1's objects in the explorer.

Please let me if this is the cause and if not how can help test2 see the objects in Object Explorer.

Comment: It may be that the Windows login belongs to a group like Administrators, and that Administrators group may have more permissions granted to it in SQL Server.  This will show up as something like "BUILTIN\Administrators" under Security->Logins.  This would explain the difference in the bahaviors if this is the case.  As to what permissions you need to add to the sql login, I'm not sure cause Management Studio is picky in that sometimes you have to give extra permissions even though they shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.
 I found a workaround. Apparently this is a bug in 2008. I grnnated view definition permission on the database (as opposed to schema) to the user and he is able to see them now.